# Okclient in Okclient cannot be applied to (okhttp3.okhttpclient)

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to use Retrofit in one of me projects.
I am facing an error with (new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))

```
 RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                 .setEndpoint(Constants.GET_API_URL_BASE)
                 .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                 .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
                 .build();
         apiGet = adapter.create(ApiCalls.class);
```

The error, underline in red, is on

> (new OkHttpClient())
>
> *** OkClient(com.squareup.okhttp.OkhttpClient) in OkClient  cannot be applied to (okhttp3.OkhttpClient)***

These are my dependences:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.7.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```

Any idea?.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Retrofit versions prior to 2.0.0-beta3 you have to use OkHttp 2. Change your OkHttp dependency to `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'` or update to Retrofit 2.

Comment: done, I am getting  "Cannot resolve symbol OkHttpClient"

Comment: You also have to change the imports from `okhttp3.*` to `com.squareup.okhttp.*`. Try `import com.squareup.okhttp.OkhttpClient;`

Answer (score 6):

You can use OkHttp3 with Retrofit 1.9 thanks to Jake Wharton and his [retrofit1-okhttp3-client](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit1-okhttp3-client)

With this library you just need to modify the `setClient()` in your `RestAdapter.Builder` to use `Ok3Client` instead of `OkClient`.

The code should be like this:

```
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
             .setEndpoint(Constants.GET_API_URL_BASE)
             .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
             .setClient(new Ok3Client(new OkHttpClient()))
             .build();
```

[Here](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-how-to-use-okhttp-3-with-retrofit-1) you can find more information about how to use it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11049109)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Where is Ok3Client?

Comment: It's in  [retrofit1-okhttp3-client](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit1-okhttp3-client)

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you @BorjaQuevedo and thank you Jake Wharton for not forcing us to update to Retrofit 2, which is a _substantial_ upgrade.